# How to overload "delete" operator in C++ to print the line and name of the file where it is used?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, macros, overloading, delete-operator

I'm trying to overload "delete" operator to print in console the line number and name of the file where it is used. I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>

void operator delete(void* adress, char* file, int line) {
    printf("%s: line %d -> ", file, line);
    delete(adress);
}

#define delete delete(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main() {
    int* x = new int;
    delete x;
}
```

But I get this compilation error (msvc, C++17):

```
Error C2146 syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'x'
```

I couldn't find any workaround. How can I solve this ?

EDIT: Here's something similar for "new" operator that works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    /* ... */
    return ptr;
}

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const int line, const char* const file) {
    printf("%s: line %d -> ", file, line);
    // BOTH RETURNS WORK
    //return malloc(size);
    return ::operator new(size);
}

#define new new(__LINE__, __FILE__)

int main() {
    int* x = new int;
    //delete x;
}
```

Comment: Try compiling with -E, see if the output makes any sense.

Comment: Try to expand the macro in your brain. `delete x;` --> `delete(__FILE__, __LINE__) x;`. Does it look syntactically valid?

Comment: Defining a macro whose name is a keyword produces undefined behavior.

Comment: I know it doesn't look syntactically valid, but I can assure you I've done something similar (almost identical) for "new" operator and it works just fine. I thought about syntax/define and I couldn't find any solution, but again it worked for "new".

Comment: "almost identical" is not "identical". Changing a single character can invalidate syntactically valid code. When dealing with macros, those subtle changes are harder to spot.

Comment: Use something other than `delete`. Whatever this is trying to do as a shortcut is probably not worth violating the rules and confusing anyone who tries to understand what's going on.

Comment: It's UB to `#define delete` if you are using *any* part of the standard library. In practise this is always the case. See [reserved macro names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Reserved_macro_names).

Comment: @JaMiT The macro is the same ...

Comment: I edited the post, now you can see the code for "new" operator.

Comment: @AndreiBădescu The stuff added by the macros is the same (albeit in reversed order), but one uses the keyword `new` while the other uses the keyword `delete`. This makes them quite different, as the keywords have different syntactical rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very dirty solution, but maybe can help for your specific case:

```
#define delete cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << endl, delete
```

However, there is a very strong limitation: It will not work if a function is declared as = delete

```
class SomeClass
{
  ...
  void fn() = delete;  // This will not compile
  ...
};
```

And then something like this must be used:

```
class SomeClass
{
  ...
#undef delete
  void fn() = delete;
#define delete cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << endl, delete
  ...
};
```

Comment: `if (something_or_other) delete something_else;` -- this will end in tears.

Comment: Ok, changed the ```;``` for ```,``` and it works

Comment: Not working if I have a special member function = delete;

Comment: You are right, it will not work in this case.